# Can we restrict the signature algorithms explicitly from client code while establishing TLS 1.3 in java?

Tags: java, security, ssl, signature, tls1.3

By default for `TLS 1.3`, the offered signature algorithms prefer ECDSA followed by RSA.
However, for my java code, I want my client to offer only RSA signature algorithms as part of client hello. How can that be achieved ?

I tried using `jdk.tls.client.SignatureSchemes="RSAWITHSHA256,RSAWITHSHA384,RSAWITHSHA512"`, but the client still presents the following algorithms as part of client hello

```
 ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1.
```

How can we achieve restricting ECDSA signature algorithms explicitly in Java client code ?

Tried setting `jdk.tls.client.SignatureSchemes="RSAWITHSHA256,RSAWITHSHA384,RSAWITHSHA512"` as system property and at runtime, it didnt work for me.

Comment: You can set the enabled cipher suites explicitly on each `SSLSocket`.

Comment: Thanks @user207421 . Actually, I am not trying to set the cipher suites. I want to restrict the signature algorithms for TLS 1.3.